# Mac Automount on Catalina does breaks when using multiple users

Tags: automount, nfs

I am trying to set up automount so that it works with multiple users signed in to my machine (macOS running Catalina). It does not work properly:

When only one user signs in after reboot, no matter which one, automount mountpoints work exactly as expected - volumes do mount, everything is accessible and works.

When another user signs in (whether it is with fast user switching or after the first user logs out), automounted points break. There are several behaviors how they break - mount points can disappear from Finder (while being still accessible and functional via Terminal), or they appear and mount, but contents display as unknown type documents (white paper icon) instead of folders. Behavior seems random, but it always stops working.

My setup is following.

In **/etc/auto_master**:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/NAS        auto_resources
```

Which points to **/etc/auto_resources**

```
Media           -fstype:afp,rw  afp://USER:PASSWORD@synology.local/NAS\ Media
Storage         -fstype:afp,rw  afp://USER:PASSWORD@synology.local/NAS\ Storage
```

I tried passing various parameters to automount, I tried different mount points, no matter what - it's the same, it works with one user, it breaks once another user signs in after reboot.

On deeper investigation, mount points still work if accessed via Terminal, all folders are there, they're accessible and work properly, but it does not work in Finder - it displays mount points as sheets of paper and they are not "folders" that Finder can browse.

How to troubleshoot this? What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated

Comment: Any ideas anyone?